# Bad approximation of non measurable set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Prove that there exists a set *A* in *R* such that the outer measure of *G-A* is infinity for any open set *G* containing *A*.
I know that this set *A* must be non measurable, and for non measurable set *A*, the outer measure of *G-A* maybe bounded below by some epsilon small, but I don't know how to give an example where the outer measure of *G-A* is infinity.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where did you read that? I did not mean so in the question.

Comment: Excuse me, I misparsed.

Comment: I am still confused. If $A \subset G $ and $G, G \setminus A$ are measurable then you must have that $A = G \setminus (G \setminus A))$ is measurable? Did you mean outer measure of $G \setminus A$?

Comment: I am sorry I mean outer measure here. I will fixed it now.

Comment: Give an equivalence relation on $\Bbb R$ such that $x,y\in\Bbb R$ are equivalent if and only if $x-y\in\Bbb Q$. Now, from each equivalence class take a point and consider a set.

Comment: Could you elaborate?